# How would you draw a matrix in Android Development?

Tags: java, android

The size of the matrix would be input by the user with variables h, w.

Given this how would I create a matrix of that size on the screen allowing the user to enter in values inside the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

probably by generateing a http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout in a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 1):

The code above doesn't quite work but it's almost there. I had to change the adds to addView.

```
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            EditText cell = new EditText(this);
            cell.setText("(" + i + ", " + j + ")");
            row.addView(cell);
        }
        table.addView(row new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)););
    }
    setContentView(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html).

I haven't used them, but I'm guessing your activity code would look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            EditText cell = new EditText(this);
            cell.setText("(" + i + ", " + j + ")");
            row.add(cell);
        }
        table.add(row);
    }
    setContentView(table);
}
```