# 10x10 table is not creating properly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-tablelayout

I want to create 10x10 grid so I am using [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149674/8274756).

**I am creating my tableView programmatically like this:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val table = TableLayout(this)
    for (i in 0..9) {
        val row = TableRow(this)
        for (j in 0..9) {
            val cell = EditText(this)
            cell.setText("test")
            row.addView(cell)
        }
        table.addView(row)
    }

    setContentView(table)
}
```

**Problem:** this will work but will replace the layout of this activity (Probably because I am calling  `setContentView(table)`)

**How can I put my table view inside `TableLayout` (it's a view inside the activity layout) instead of my current resault?**

---

For better understanding, my current code gives me this result (as I mentioned above):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout the [Android basics](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp) first.

Anyway. Put your `TableLayout` into your layout, use `findViewById()` and use it instead of creating a new one.

```
val table = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.tablelayout)
for (i in 0..9) {
 // ... Same code
}
```

Comment: Well funny thing, I did it before asking the question and got a weird non-related error. Now I have simply used `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and it worked (Just as your answer mentioned to use `findViewById()` ). I will accept it within 10 minutes.